# easy to use control panel for minecraft rcon

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I wrote a small program that connects to a minecraft rcon and provides an easy to use control panel.
It is written in python 3.9 and uses the kivy module for the GUI.

What could I improve in the code? Are the variable names easy to understand and if not, how could I improve them?

Here is the main.py and the pmcp.kv:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from mcrcon import MCRcon as r
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import sys
import os

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    
    connection_refused = True
    while connection_refused:
        ip = str(input('enter ip or hostname of the server:\n>'))   

        try:                   
            port = int(input('enter the server port (default: 25575):\n>'))
            if port not in range(0,65535+1):
                raise ValueError          
        except ValueError:
            print('invalid value! using default.')
            port = 25575
                    
        pw = str(input('enter server password:\n>'))

        try:
            with r (host=ip, port=port, password=pw) as mcr: 
                mcr.command('list')
                connection_refused = False
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print('connection refused, try again!')
            connection_refused = True

    player_count = StringProperty('')
    selected_player = StringProperty('')
    lives_to_add = StringProperty('')   

    def player_count_refresh(self):        
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('list')
    
    def selected_player_submit(self):
        self.selected_player = str(self.ids.textinput_selected_player.text) 
                
    def player_heal(self):        
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('effect give '+self.selected_player+' minecraft:instant_health 1 50')
                    
    def player_tp_to_spawn(self):
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('tp '+self.selected_player+' 0 ~ 0')
        
    def player_add_lives(self):
        self.lives_to_add = str(self.ids.slider_player_lives_to_add.value)
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('setlives '+self.selected_player+' '+self.lives_to_add)
        
    def player_revoke_progress(self):  
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('advancement revoke '+self.selected_player+' everything')        

    def player_give_op(self):
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('op '+self.selected_player) 

    def player_revoke_op(self):
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('deop '+self.selected_player) 
    
    def player_kick(self):
        with r (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('kick '+self.selected_player) 
    
class PyMinecraftContolPanel(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('pmcp.kv')        
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))

    PyMinecraftContolPanel().run()
```

pmcp.kv:

```
#:kivy 2.0.0

<MainWindow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'  
   
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1,None
        size: 1, '60dp'

        Label:
            id: label_player_count
            text: root.player_count
            
        Button:
            id: button_player_count_refresh
            text: 'refresh'
            on_press: root.player_count_refresh()
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '60dp', '60dp'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1,None
        size: 1, '60dp'

        TextInput:
            id: textinput_selected_player
            text: 'enter player to select:'
            multiline: False
            on_focus: self.text = ''
            
        Button:
            id: button_selected_player_submit
            text: 'select\nplayer'
            on_press: root.selected_player_submit()
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '60dp', '60dp'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 8

        Button:
            id: button_player_heal
            text: 'heal player'
            on_press: root.player_heal()

        Button:
            id: button_player_tp_to_spawn
            text: 'tp to spawn'
            on_press: root.player_tp_to_spawn()

        Button:
            id: button_player_add_lives
            text: 'add lives'
            on_press: root.player_add_lives()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            
            Label:
                text: 'lives\nto\nadd'                
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: 1
                text_size: self.width, None   
                halign: 'center'             
                           
            Label:
                text: str(slider_player_lives_to_add.value) 
                size_hint_y: None
                size_hint_x: 1               
                text_size: self.width, None   
                halign: 'center' 

            Slider:
                id: slider_player_lives_to_add
                min: 1
                max: 10
                step: 1
                orientation: 'vertical'
                            
        Button:
            id: button_player_revoke_progress
            text: 'revoke\nprogress'
            on_press: root.player_revoke_progress()

        Button:
            id: button_player_give_op
            text: 'give op'
            on_press: root.player_give_op()

        Button:
            id: button_player_revoke_op
            text: 'revoke op'
            on_press: root.player_revoke_op()

        Button:
            id: button_player_kick
            text: 'kick'
            on_press: root.player_kick()

MainWindow:
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that running the code from `connection_refused = True` onward in `MainWindow`'s static scope is a good idea. Maybe you intended on this being in the constructor? In which case you need an `__init__`.

This loop:

```
    connection_refused = True
    while connection_refused:
        # ...
        try:
            with r (host=ip, port=port, password=pw) as mcr: 
                mcr.command('list')
                connection_refused = False
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print('connection refused, try again!')
            connection_refused = True
```

should not need a flag variable, and should instead be

```
    while True:
        # ...
        try:
            with r (host=ip, port=port, password=pw) as mcr: 
                mcr.command('list')
                break
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print('connection refused, try again!')
```

You should not need to use a `str` cast here:

```
    ip = str(input('enter ip or hostname of the server:\n>'))
```

since the return of `input` is already a `str`.

Your error handling here:

```
    try:                   
        port = int(input('enter the server port (default: 25575):\n>'))
        if port not in range(0,65535+1):
            raise ValueError          
    except ValueError:
        print('invalid value! using default.')
        port = 25575
```

first of all would benefit from showing two separate, more specific error messages; and also have a constant defined for the default port:

```
DEFAULT_PORT = 25575

try:                   
    port = int(input(f'enter the server port (default: {DEFAULT_PORT}):\n>'))
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid integer! Using default.')
    port = DEFAULT_PORT

if not (0 <= port < 65536):
    print('Port out of range! Using default.')
    port = DEFAULT_PORT
```

This import:

```
from mcrcon import MCRcon as r
```

is mysterious and converts a good name into a bad name. Just leave it as `from mcrcon import MCRcon`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help, i will look into everything you mentioned and will post an update when i got everything sorted. This import: "from mcrcon import MCRcon as r" was suggested from the mcrcon module documentation, but you are totally right, in a more complex program this "r" import would be unnecessarily complicated to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Is there more that I could improve? This is the updated code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from mcrcon import MCRcon
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import sys
import os
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')
Config.write()

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    DEFAULT_PORT = 25575
    
    while True:
        try:                   
            ip = input('enter ip or hostname of the server:\n>')
            port = int(input('enter the server port (default: 25575):\n>'))
            if not(0 <= port < 65536):
                print('invalid port! using default port(25575)')      
                port = DEFAULT_PORT   

        except ValueError:
            print('invalid value, only integer! using default port(25575).')
            port = DEFAULT_PORT

        try:
            pw = input('enter server password:\n>')
            with MCRcon (host=ip, port=port, password=pw) as mcr: 
                mcr.command('list')                            
                if sys.platform=="win32":
                    import ctypes
                    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0 )
            break

        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            print('connection refused, try again!')
        except TimeoutError:
            print('connection timed out, try again!')
            
    player_count = StringProperty('')
    selected_player = StringProperty('')
    lives_to_set = StringProperty('')   

    def player_count_refresh(self):        
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('list')
    
    def selected_player_submit(self):
        self.selected_player = str(self.ids.textinput_selected_player.text) 
                
    def player_heal(self):        
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('effect give '+self.selected_player+' minecraft:instant_health 1 50')
                    
    def player_tp_to_spawn(self):
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('tp '+self.selected_player+' 0 ~ 0')
        
    def player_set_lives(self):
        self.lives_to_set = str(self.ids.slider_player_lives_to_set.value)
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('setlives '+self.selected_player+' '+self.lives_to_set)
        
    def player_revoke_progress(self):  
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('advancement MCRconevoke '+self.selected_player+' everything')        

    def player_give_op(self):
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('op '+self.selected_player) 

    def player_revoke_op(self):
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('deop '+self.selected_player) 
    
    def player_kick(self):
        with MCRcon (host=self.ip, port=self.port, password=self.pw) as mcr:
            self.player_count = mcr.command('kick '+self.selected_player) 
    
class PyMinecraftContolPanel(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file('pymcp.kv')        
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))

    PyMinecraftContolPanel().run()
```